# change css style with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have this style sheet

```
#navigation {
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

#navigation ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  border-right: solid 1px #5f5f5f;
  padding-right: 8px;
  margin-right:8px;
}
```

this is the HTML

```
      <div id="navigation" >
            <ul dir="rtl">
                <li>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonRegister" runat="server" Visible="true" CausesValidation="False"
                        PostBackUrl="~/Register.aspx">הרשמה</asp:LinkButton>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonLogin" runat="server" Visible="true" CausesValidation="False">התחבר</asp:LinkButton>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonLogout" runat="server" Visible="false" OnClick="ButtonLogOut_Click"
                        CausesValidation="False">התנתק</asp:LinkButton>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonMyAccount" runat="server" Visible="false" CausesValidation="False"
                        PostBackUrl="~/MyAccount.aspx">אזור אישי</asp:LinkButton>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

How can I change the " #navigation ul li " 'float' attribute to 'right' ?

i can reach the div navigation with javascript-
documnet.getelementbyid("navigation"), but have no idea how to get into the style of each li which is defined in the style sheet

Comment: Please explain the `javascript` tag..?

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do this. Changing the rules of the stylesheet itself is not trivial, because of certain cross browser issues. So probably there is a better solution then changing the rule itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vanilla JS you first need to get the navigation element using **getElementById**, then get all its list items using **getElementsByTagName**. Then, iterating through the list items you can set **element.style.float**:

```
var nav = document.getElementById("navigation"),
    lis = nav.getElementsByTagName("li"),
    l = lis.length,
    i = 0;
for (i; i < l; i++) { 
    lis[i].style.float = "right";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing this in the stylesheet, but if you don't have access to that, you can use JavaScript similar to the following:

```
// get all of the DOM nodes which match the selector
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("#navigation ul li");
// loop through all of the nodes
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  // set the style
  nodes[i].style.float = "right";
}
```

NOTE: `document.querySelectorAll` will only work on modern browsers (Chrome, Safari, FF, IE9+).

Answer (score 2):

Do you want output like this [Check the example](http://jsfiddle.net/m9DYs/2/)

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("navigation").style.cssFloat = "right";
```

inside Body tag

```
  <div id="navigation" >
        <ul dir="rtl">
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonRegister" runat="server" Visible="true" CausesValidation="False"
                    PostBackUrl="~/Register.aspx">הרשמה</asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonLogin" runat="server" Visible="true" CausesValidation="False">התחבר</asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonLogout" runat="server" Visible="false" OnClick="ButtonLogOut_Click"
                    CausesValidation="False">התנתק</asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonMyAccount" runat="server" Visible="false" CausesValidation="False"
                    PostBackUrl="~/MyAccount.aspx">אזור אישי</asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

css code

```
#navigation {
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

#navigation ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  border-right: solid 1px #5f5f5f;
  padding-right: 8px;
  margin-right:8px;
}
```

Comment: You should explain what you have changed and why.

Comment: I just added javascript code document.getElementById("navigation").style.cssFloat = "right";

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you can add dynamic style sheet:

```
var sheet = document.createElement('style')
sheet.innerHTML = "#navigation ul li {float: right;}";
document.body.appendChild(sheet);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function:

```js
function style(selector, cssStyle, final) {           // make a style function with paramaters: selecctor (the selector you want to style e.g '.test'), cssStyle (the style you would like to change e.g. 'fontFamily'), and final (e.g 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif')
  const elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);  // actually get the elements
  for (const elem of elems) {                         // loop through all the elements
    elem.style[cssStyle] = final;                     // change the element's style of cssStyle to final using square brackets (e.g.({ test: true })['test'] outputs true)
  }
}
/**
  * Example:
  * Style all h1s' font family to Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif:
  */
    style(
      'h1',
      'fontFamily',
      'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'
    );
/**
  * Style all ps' background image to linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, yellow):
  */
    style(
      'p',
      'backgroundImage',
      'linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, yellow)'
    );
/**
  * You get it, its pretty cool
  * For your situation:
 */
    style(
      '#navigation ul li',
      'float',
      'right'
    )
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change that dinamycally (you have "javascript" tag in the question) put this in your javascript (on the desired event)

```
$("#navigation ul li").css("float", "right");
```

I assume you have Jquery included!

Comment: You shouldn't have assumed that, do you see jQuery mentioned?

Comment: I'm just sugesting a solution, anyways the question isn't clear enough. Jquery is used in 95% of the websites, so there is a big chance to help with that.